# Is it possible to publish an app to Windows Phone Marketplace as _free_ and later change the price?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

Is it possible to publish an app to Windows Phone Marketplace as *free* and later change the price of the *very* same app, *without* changing anything else?
I mean the stats, reviews etc remains in this case, the app is the same, the price raised from free to some value after a promo time period, say 3 months.

I know that it is possible with Apple AppStore, I also know it is not possible with Android Market (btw what about Amazon Android store?, but this is out of topic here)

Unfortunately I did not find related info about WP7/WP7.5 Marketplace.

Thx for answers

Comment: Interestingly after more than 7.5 years ago the OP was issued, and also way after the whole platforms is executed to be dead, so nobody is interested, neither in general neither the technology, neither this particular issue, someone cared enough, and take her/his time to express her/his negative opinion. Wow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. With the one limit that users that have already "purchased" the application (for $0), won't be asked to pay for it when you change the price.

Not even if they re-install the app.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably possible (at least it was) as I remember a bug where apps that converted from free to paid could not be updated by the end-user and that very same bug also existed with apps that have trial versions.

Edit: I'm pretty sure you can change from free to paid, but for the other way, your app needs certification again which means republishing it. MSDN especially states that special condition.

Comment: It is possible to change the price whenever you want, for each country. Price updates usually take 2 to 3 days to be propagated to the marketplace.

Note that users who downloaded the app while it was free will still have it on their phone.